# Write special character in bash string

Tags: bash

I want to do the following:

```
echo 'truncate \'testTruncate\' "|hbase shell
```

Probably the problem is with the ' char.

Do you know how can I solve it?

I get syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use external `"` instead:

```
echo "truncate 'testTruncate' "|hbase shell
```

Comment: Thank you it works!

Comment: Limited applicability

Answer (score 1):

You can include a `'` in a string that is quoted by `'` as follows:

```
echo 'O'\''Brien'
```

or

```
echo 'O'"'"'Brien'
```

In both case you will get `O'Brien` as output. Note that in both case, we there essetially 3 strings, one next to the other, e.g. `'O'`, `\'`, `'Brien'`.

This looks ugly, but unfortunately backslash escapes are not supported in single quoted strings in bash.

Comment: What will be the output in this example?

Comment: Thank you it works!